# SQL: Combining columns from two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables **A** and **B**, each consisting of the columns **nr** and **name**. The numbers-column in **A** is a subset of the numbers-column in **B**. Now, I would like to create a new table **C** consisting of the columns **nr**, **name_A** and **name_B**, where **name_A** is taken from the name-column in A (if the nr exists in **A**, '-' otherwise) and where **name_B** is taken from the name-column in **B**.

The best I have been able to figure out so far is:

```
CREATE TABLE C
  SELECT * FROM A
    UNION
  SELECT * FROM B;
```

This is obviously not giving me the structure I ask for, so help would be highly appreciated from a SQL-newbie.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` would be used for this.

Answer (score 2):

The tool you're looking for is a [left] join:

```
CREATE TABLE c AS
SELECT       b.nr, COALESCE(a.name, '-') AS name_a, b.name AS b.name
FROM         b
LEFT JOIN    a on b.nr = a.nr
```